# How to change Joomla 3.0 Template name?

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla! 3.0.2 website and I want to change Ja_onepage template folder name, I followed this 3 step solution but it didn't work.

Change the foldername ( templates/FOLDERNAME )
Change the [name] in templateDetails.xml in several places (Use Replace Tool)
Change the Language File: en-GB.tpl_NEW-NAME.ini

When I do that I can not access to the website, How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Joomla changed system, so it's not so easy - as it was in Joomla 1.5.
Now after installation you have to change name in database and sometimes in template files.

Joomla 3.0.2 - is very old version, is not safe anymore.

p.s.
Second your template is commercial so you can use support from developer.

Answer (score 2):

***As mentioned already upgrade the site it's not secure.***

Assuming you want to actually copy the entire templates files (i.e. php, css, js etc) and not create a template style you can [do this through the template manager](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Modifying_a_Joomla!_Template#Copy_an_Existing_Template).

In Joomla 3.x you can use the `Copy Template` button in the template manager.

1. Select Extensions -> Template Manger
    [image: Joomla 3.x Template Manager Menu Item]
2. This opens by default in the `Styles` view, click on the `Template` view button:
   [image: Template Menu Item in Template Manager Sidebar]
3. Click on the name of the template you want to copy e.g. Isis template:
   [image: Isis Template in Joomla Template Manager]
4. Click on the "Copy Template" button in the top left.
   [image: Copy Template in Joomla Template Manager]
5. Joomla then asks for a name for the template.
   [image: Provide a new name for the template in Joomla Template Manager]

That's it… then you can modify the files to your hearts content.

Reasons this won't work — a lot of templates from commercial providers used to work with this process when it first came out, but, our recent experience is that while the files copy the templates don't work as expected. I'm guessing here but I suspect it's because all the major template providers seems to have move to template frameworks and something gets missed in the copy by Joomla.

This question might get better answers on the [Joomla Q&A site on Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks @cppl, But there is no copy option available !

Comment: Ah... yes I just checked back through the release notes and the improved template manager was part of 3.2 - sorry about that. http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5516-joomla-3-2-0-stable-released.html